# MYSQL - How to select a row with a certain value, but only if it appears once?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example this is my table 'students':

```
   date     |     studentid  
-------------------------------  
 17/02      |     1  
 18/02      |     2  
 19/02      |     1  
 17/02      |     3  
 17/02      |     4
```

So I'm trying to get a query that selects the studentids only on the date 17/02 and only if the studentid appears once in the studentid column.

The desired output is:

```
   date     |     studentid  
-----------------------------  
 17/02      |     3  
 17/02      |     4
```

This is what I tried so far, but because the where clause is performed before having by it doesn't work.

```
SELECT studentid  
FROM students  
WHERE date = '17/02'  
GROUP BY studentid  
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can put the date check in the `HAVING` clause as well.

```
SELECT MAX(date) as date, studentid
FROM students
GROUP BY studentid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND date = '17/02'
```

`MAX(date)` is necessary because all columns not listed in `GROUP BY` need to be aggregated. If the studentid only appears once, there's only one date so it will be the max (and also min).

Comment: Thanks Barman! And what if I wanted just the studentids to display with no date?

Comment: Use this as a subquery in a query that just selects the studentid.

Comment: `select studentid from (above query) x`

Comment: Why a subquery? `SELECT studentid
FROM students
GROUP BY studentid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MAX(date) = '17/02'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE
date = '17/02/2020'
AND studentid IN
(SELECT studentid
FROM Students
GROUP BY studentid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self outer join, filtering out those which have another row.

```
SELECT a.studentid  
FROM students a
LEFT JOIN students b ON a. studentid = b.studentid
  AND b.date != a.date
WHERE a.date = '17/02/2020'  
AND b.studentid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

**Demo:**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3275018133908423a003108d34024afe

```
select studentid from (SELECT min(a.date) as dt,a.studentid
FROM students a
group by a.studentid
having count(a.studentid)=1) u
where dt='17/02'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to insert `DISTINCT` in your query?

> *The `SELECT DISTINCT` statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.*
>
> *Inside a table, a column often contains many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.* [1](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

**Query**

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT studentid  
FROM students  
WHERE date = '17/02/2020'  
GROUP BY studentid;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   date     |     studentid  
-----------------------------  
 17/02      |     3  
 17/02      |     4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from students s
where s2.date = '2020-02-17' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from students s2
                  where s2.studentid = s.studentid and
                        s2.date <> s.date
                 );
```

This can take advantage of *two* indexes for performance:  `students(date)` and `students(studentid, date)`.  It should be pretty fast with those indexes.

Also, note the use of standard date formats.  You should be storing the date as a native type (say `date`).  And you should be using YYYY-MM-DD formatted date constants.

This makes the reasonable assumption (well, reasonable to me) that students do not have duplicated rows on the same date.